# Generate thumbnail for multiple file formats

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, thumbnails, google-cloud-storage

For the purpose of creating thumbnails for files like pdf, jpg, and docx, I'm looking for a library or service. My server stores data on GCS, and the front-end application should only display brief file previews.

If the thumbnail doesn't already exist, I'd like to create it, save it to gcs, and serve it with a signed url.

I found a few solutions:

- [filepreview-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepreview-es6) library - updated 5 years ago
- [filepreviews.io](https://filepreviews.io/) - external service - the data are confidential
- [gotenberg.dev](https://gotenberg.dev/) - returns only pdfs

How to implement this feature in 2022?

Comment: filepreview-es6 is just a js script which uses `child_process` to spawn `convert` (imagemagic) and  `ffmpeg` commands to generate images [1](https://github.com/sahilsharmafrank/filepreview/blob/master/filepreview.js). I would write my own code instead instead using this library.  May be using 3rd party service would be better.

Comment: @bogdanoff Thank you, I consider to rewrite this in Typescript. I am surprised that nobody have done it before - many apps has the similar feature.